# Googleドライブをマウントしたcolab上で解凍したzipファイル（概ね10万ファイル以上）の異常

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-platform, gzip

colabでGoogleドライブをマウントして使う時，colab上でうまくzipファイルを解凍できません．同様の問題を抱えている人はいますか？

Comment: 「異常」や「うまくいかない」だけでは第三者は判断しようがないので、どのように解凍しようとしているか実際のコードや、もしエラーメッセージ等が出ているようであればそれらも質問に追記した方が回答が付きやすいです。 / ファイル数の多さから勝手に想像すると、Google Drive 上に十分な空き容量があるかも確認してみてください。